# How to send dynamic amount of HTML forms to controller as list of objects?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am doing a .NET Core MVC project. In a partial view, I want some information from user to fill as HTML form. That information is variables of a model, so every filled list is an object. After user filled the objects, I want to send that object to my controller as a List of that object. User may send 3 forms or 5 forms or 1 form. My question is, when it is only 1 form to send, everything was ok, I gave variables names' of model as name attribute to my HTML inputs in a form tag and my object was filling. But in that case which I don't know how many objects will come, I could not figure out how can I get list of objects. I hope it is clear.

Here is my View:

```
@model List<EpubAdmin.Models.KyProducts>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddBook";
    Layout = null;
}

@foreach(var product in Model)
{
    <div class="col col-xl-12">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        

        <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 ">
            <form method="post" action="/File/AddProductFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
                
                <br />
                <b>Kitap Adı: </b>
                <input class="form-control" value="@(Html.Raw(product.Name))" name="Name"/>
                <br />
                <b>Sayfa Sayısı: </b>
                <input class="form-control" value="@product.PageNumber" name="PageNumber" />
                <br />
                <b>Product Id: </b>
                <input class="form-control" value="@product.KyProductId" name="KyProductId" readonly />
                <br />
                <b>Barkod:  </b>
                <input class="form-control" value="@product.Barcode" name="Barcode" readonly />
                <input class="form-control" value="@product.Author" name="Author" hidden />
                <input class="form-control" value="@product.ImageId" name="ImageId" hidden />
                <input class="form-control" value="@product.PublisherName" name="PublisherName" hidden />
                <input class="form-control" value="@product.PublisherId" name="PublisherId" hidden />
                
                <br />
                @*<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-show-subtext="true">
                        <option value="0">Tarih</option>
                        <option value="1">Çocuk</option>
                        <option value="2">Psikoloji</option>
                        <option value="3">Kültür</option>
                    </select>*@
                @if (product.IsDuplicate)
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p>* Bu kitap zaten ekli.</p>
                    </div>}

                else
                {
                    <h5>Kategori Seç</h5>
                    <select class="form-select ml-0" data-live-search="true">
                        <option selected>Tarih</option>
                        <option value="1">Çocuk</option>
                        <option value="2">Psikoloji</option>
                        <option value="3">Kültür</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-select ml-5">
                        <option selected>Tarih</option>
                        <option value="1">Çocuk</option>
                        <option value="2">Psikoloji</option>
                        <option value="3">Kültür</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-select ml-5">
                        <option selected>Tarih</option>
                        <option value="1">Çocuk</option>
                        <option value="2">Psikoloji</option>
                        <option value="3">Kültür</option>
                    </select>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <label for="file">Yüklenecek kitabı seçin.</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="File" accept=".epub" name="File">   
                }
            </form>
            <br />         
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <br />
</div>
}

<div class="float-right">
    <button class="btn btn-info w-100" onclick="onclk()">Ekle</button>
</div>
<br />
<br />


<script>  
    function onclk() {
        $("#myForm").submit();       
        alert("a");
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddProductFile(List<KyProducts> model)                                              
        {
            foreach(var product in model)
            {
                if (product.file == null || product.KyProductId == 0 || product.PublisherId == 0)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("List", "Books");
                }
}
}
```

I thought about using for instead of foreach in my view so I can get indexes and can name my HTML attributes as `name="id+@i"` but that did not seem best practice to me and wasn't sure if it works. I also thought about putting hidden submit buttons for every form and on click of main submit button, triggering all hidden submit buttons but that didn't seem to be best practice again... What are your ideas?

Comment: If you want the user to be able to submit each product individually, and validation is independent as well, then having multiple forms is fine. You won't be able to submit multiple forms at once, since each one triggers a request to the URL in the `action` attribute. You should also ensure that each form has a unique ID; currently they would all have the same ID and the button would only submit the first form. If you want the user to only be able to submit all of them at once, then a single form is best. Maybe add a hidden field with something that uniquely identifies the product.

Comment: I want user to be able to submit all of them at once but I also need to validate them one by one if they are in the format that I want.Because then I write them to db. And about having multiple forms, did you mean like what I did with a loop or some amount of forms, because I will not know how much I need It will depend on the list's size coming to me. And I think I don't need to submit them as forms maybe, I am thinking about If I can do something with ajax request If I can get the whole filled list in view. Also what do you think about giving them id's with their indexes so they can be uniqu

Comment: Or maybe I give up with this and just add a + icon next to each product, then I want user to press the + "just to be sure" they want to add them and each time they press + with another controller I take them and turn them a list. That would be much easier :)

Comment: :) Very true. Simpler is often better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a list to your action,try to put the form outside `foreach`,and change the name of inputs:

```
@model List<EpubAdmin.Models.KyProducts>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddBook";
    Layout = null;
}
<form method="post" action="/File/AddProductFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
    @{ var i = 0;}
    @foreach (var product in Model)
    {
        <div class="col col-xl-12">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">


                <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 ">


                    <br />
                    <b>Kitap Adı: </b>
                    <input class="form-control" value="@(Html.Raw(product.Name))" name="model[@i].Name" />
                    <br />
                    <b>Sayfa Sayısı: </b>
                    <input class="form-control" value="@product.PageNumber" name="model[@i].PageNumber" />
                    <br />
                    <b>Product Id: </b>
                    <input class="form-control" value="@product.KyProductId" name="model[@i].KyProductId" readonly />
                    <br />
                    <b>Barkod:  </b>
                    <input class="form-control" value="@product.Barcode" name="model[@i].Barcode" readonly />
                    <input class="form-control" value="@product.Author" name="model[@i].Author" hidden />
                    <input class="form-control" value="@product.ImageId" name="model[@i].ImageId" hidden />
                    <input class="form-control" value="@product.PublisherName" name="model[@i].PublisherName" hidden />
                    <input class="form-control" value="@product.PublisherId" name="model[@i].PublisherId" hidden />

                    <br />

                    @if (product.IsDuplicate)
                    {
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <p>* Bu kitap zaten ekli.</p>
                        </div>}

                    else
                    {
                        <h5>Kategori Seç</h5>
                        <select class="form-select ml-0" data-live-search="true">
                            <option selected>Tarih</option>
                            <option value="1">Çocuk</option>
                            <option value="2">Psikoloji</option>
                            <option value="3">Kültür</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-select ml-5">
                            <option selected>Tarih</option>
                            <option value="1">Çocuk</option>
                            <option value="2">Psikoloji</option>
                            <option value="3">Kültür</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-select ml-5">
                            <option selected>Tarih</option>
                            <option value="1">Çocuk</option>
                            <option value="2">Psikoloji</option>
                            <option value="3">Kültür</option>
                        </select>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <label for="file">Yüklenecek kitabı seçin.</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="File" accept=".epub" name="File">
                    }

                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <hr />
            <br />
        </div>
        i++;
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

So that when you click the button,it will pass the whole list to action.